# In the Category of $\mathbf{ Set } $ is "the product of an empty set of sets a one-element set"?

Tags: category-theory

I was reading [these notes](http://fsl.cs.illinois.edu/images/a/a8/CS522-Fall-2018-Category-Theory-slides.pdf) on Category Theory and it said (paraphrased to add context):

> Exercise 4: Explain why in Set (the Category of Sets), the product of an empty set of sets is a one-element set.

which I think is incorrect. The product of two empty sets (or any number) is empty because we are considering:

$$ \emptyset \times \emptyset = \{ (a,b) : a \in \emptyset, b \in \emptyset \} = \emptyset$$

where $a \in \emptyset , b \in \emptyset$ are false, so the above is the $\emptyset$ which is NOT a one element set (its a zero element set).

This should be trivial so I am assuming I am somewhere mis reading the natural language of the exercise. Someone help me catch where is it? i.e whats being asked and what the answer is?

Comment: I think the answer is not $\emptyset$, but rather $\{\emptyset\}$.

Comment: @TheCount is the product of empty sets is $\{ \emptyset \}$? I think I just don't know whats being asked at the moment. I understand products and limits in categories...

Comment: In a general category, a product of an empty set of objects is exactly the same as a final object (if either exists).

Comment: @DanielSchepler oh I see so they are asking what object in $\prod_{X \in Ob(C) } X$ is?

Comment: @Pinocchio i claim to know for sure. i'm just guessing that's the idea. the thing inside the brackets is all the things you get from the products.

Comment: My interpretation is: for example, the limit of a discrete $n$-object diagram with objects $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$ is $X_1 \times X_2 \times \cdots X_n$.  What is the limit of the empty diagram (case $n=0$)?

Comment: @DanielSchepler oh ok that changes things a lot. Then $X^0 = 1$ where $1$ is a single-set element. It's just the question of what the set $X^0$ which is mapping nothing to a set $X$ which obviously is only the function that does "nothing" (the single element in the set 1). Formally $X^0 = \{ f: \emptyset \to X \} = \{ \{ (a,b) \in A \times B : \forall a \in \emptyset , \exists b \in B \} \} = \{ \emptyset \}$.

Comment: @JohnDouma weird! it submitted my question twice. Probably some weird server bug? We should merge these two questions.

Comment: Well, it wouldn't be precisely $X^0$ since there's no $X$ to be seen in an empty family you're taking a product of.  But for example, you might view $\prod_{i\in I} X_i$ as the set of functions $I \to \bigcup_{i\in I} X_i$ such that $f(i) \in X_i$ for each $i \in I$.  Then under this characterization of an "indexed product", if the index set $I = \emptyset$ then you can use a similar argument to show the unique function $\emptyset \to \bigcup_{i \in \emptyset} X_i = \emptyset$ satisfying this condition (vacuously) is the empty function.

Comment: However, I'd say the interpretation of an empty product as "the limit of an empty diagram" would be the interpretation more in line with general category theory.

Comment: @DanielSchepler ok then $X^0 = \{ \emptyset \}$ by definition. Just like empty conjunction is defined to be true by definition?

Comment: @DanielSchepler ok yes your comment makes sense. I am happy with the $\emptyset \to \cup_{i \in \emptyset_set} X_i$ interpretation.